# appending values to a new dataframe and making one of the datatypes the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a new Data-frame `df`.  Which was created using:

```
df= pd.DataFrame()
```

I have a date value called `'day'` which is in format dd-mm-yyyy and a cost value called `'cost`'.

How can I append the date and cost values to the df and assign the date as the index?

So for example if I have the following values
day = 01-01-2001
cost = 123.12

the resulting df would look like

```
      date   cost
01-01-2001 123.12
```

I will eventually be adding paired values for multiple days, so the df will eventually look something like:

```
      date   cost
01-01-2001 123.12
02-01-2001  23.25
03-01-2001 124.23
    :        :
01-07-2016  2.214
```

I have tried to append the paired values to the data frame but am unsure of the syntax. I've tried various thinks including the below but without success.

```
df.append([day,cost], columns='date,cost',index_col=[0])
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to append a row at a time? This is non-performant as you will cause re-allocation when it needs to grow the df

Comment: I have a process that is run over each day and returns the date and the cost.  Would it be easier to write them to a list?  The end game is that I want to write the values to a csv.  Thanks

Comment: Pandas isn't very good at building things a row at a time.  You would probably be better off appending new results to file, then loading the whole thing using `pd.read_csv` when you need it for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dfapp = [day,cost]
df.append(dfapp)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here.  First, making a column the index goes like this, though you can also do it when you load the dataframe from a file (see below):

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

To add new rows, you should write them out to file first.  Pandas isn't great at adding rows dynamically, and this way you can just read the data in when you need it for analysis.

```
new_row = ... #a row of new data in string format with values 
              #separated by commas and ending with \n

with open(path, 'a') as f:
    f.write(new_row)
```

You can do this in a loop, or singly, as many time as you need.  Then when you're ready to work with it, you use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

`index_col` can't take a string name for the index column, so you have to use the index of the order on disk; in my case it makes the first column the index.  Passing `parse_dates=True` will make it turn your datetime strings that you declared as the index into datetime objects.